# Xlwings expand() function skips rows with empty cells

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm trying to read excel files with xlwings.  I noticed that when I use expand() function it's not able to read past any rows with empty cells.  So for example I have the starting cell as A1 but cell A2 is an empty cell so it only reads row 1.  If I remove row 2 completely then it reads all the data in the excel file.  Is there a way to get it to read all rows regardless of empty cells or not?  That is with ONLY specifying the starting cell for the cell range?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced there is better way to do this, but I got what you wanted by something like the following:

```py
print(sheet.range('A1').current_region.columns[1].value)
```

This prints the first column and can read past blank cells as you struggled. However, note that in the chain of methods that were used, `range('A1')` was there only because you can not use method `current_region` unless you have some range object before that. So you can actually change the `A1` in `range('A1')` into any cell name you want and still got the same result, as long as you keep the method after `current_region` to be `columns[1]`.